# Required boolean field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a boolean field,

```
is_operable = BooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(choices=YES_OR_NO, renderer=InlineRadioFieldRenderer), required=False, initial=True)
```

Which is rendered as two radio buttons (yes or no), but I want it to be required. The problem is that if I change it to `required=True`, it throws a validation error when it gets `False`.

Is there a way around this?

---

```
YES_OR_NO = (
    (True, 'Yes'),
    (False, 'No')
)
```

Comment: "choices=YES_OR_NO"?  Is False one of the choices?  Please UPDATE your question with the missing code.

Comment: a workaround, instead of specifying required=True, specify a initial value of True/False.

Comment: @S.Lott: Sorry. Thought it could have been inferred. Updated question. @Ashok: I have provided an initial value... but the problem isn't just getting them to choose *something*, it's from a UI perspective I put "(optional)" beside all the non-required fields.

Comment: @Mark: Nothing can be "inferred".  We can't guess what code you're using.  The part you didn't post could harbor the error.

Comment: @S.Lott: There was no error; that was the expected output, just not the output I wanted.

Comment: @Mark: "expected output, just not the output I wanted"?  That's hard to interpret.  Does that mean you wished Django was magically different than it actually is?  What does that mean?

Comment: @S.Lott: Something like that. Django treats `False` as failing the "required" condition. Whether or not that is good behavior is debatable, but it's not what I want.

Comment: @Mark: "but it's not what I want".  "that was the expected output".  So you want something that Django does not do?  Is that what this question is?

Comment: @S.Lott: No. Django (apparently) *can* do what I want, just not with the way I have written it. What I wrote produced documented expected behavior, according to the Django specs, so I needed to find another way to write it such that it avoids said behavior. Are you just trying to torment me now?

Comment: @Mark: No.  I'm baffled by your comments.  "but it's not what I want". "that was the expected output".  Is very, very confusing.  If it does what you expected then you cannot possibly have a question.

Comment: @S.Lott: Yes I can! Fine. Let's put it this way. There was a *bug* in *my* code. *Django* didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: @Mark: So "that was the expected output, just not the output I wanted" means you knew you had a bug?  You expected the bug?  So your question is "I have a bug that I know about?"  Or "It does what I expected, but why does it work that way?"  I'm really having a hard time understanding what you didn't know and what you are asking to learn that you didn't already know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a `TypedChoiceField` which coerces the choices `YES_OR_NO` into a boolean. See the docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.TypedChoiceField

Comment: Yessir, that's an easy fix :) `TypedChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=YES_OR_NO, required=True, initial=True, empty_value=None, coerce=bool)`

Comment: Wouldn't `bool` just coerce both values to `True`? Specifically, `bool('False')` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Correct. `coerce=bool` won't work since `bool('False')` is `True`. You would need a custom coerce function. ex. `lambda x: x == 'True'`

Answer (score 3):

Leave it as `required=False` and write a custom `clean_is_operable` method that checks that you've got what you want, else throws a ValidationError or the like