# Django form-wizard typechoicefield returning string instead of boolean

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-formwizard, choicefield

so i am using Django 1.3 form-wizard https://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard and i am running into problems with my typechoice field which is returning `u'False'` instead of just `False (boolean)`.

What should i do?

```
ONE_OR_MULTIPLE_CHOICES = (
    (False, 'One'),
    (True, 'Multiple')
)

class PublicJobCreateForm(forms.Form):
    multiple = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=ONE_OR_MULTIPLE_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

i am calling this way:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    create_form_data = form_list[0].cleaned_data
    if create_form_data['multiple']:
        print "something"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified `coerce` for your [`TypedChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield).

```
ONE_OR_MULTIPLE_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'One'),
    (1, 'Multiple')
)

multiple = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=ONE_OR_MULTIPLE_CHOICES,
                                  widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                  coerce=int)
```

If you want to use `False` and `True` instead of `0` and `1`, then note that using `coerce=bool` does not work. This is because the string `'False'` is coerced to `True`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415022/113962) suggests to use a custom lambda function:

```
coerce = lambda x: x == 'True'
```

Comment: @psychok7 I was just about to change my answer back but then I saw you'd removed your comment. Does using the lambda function for coerce work?

Comment: i went back the answer that you wrote (0 and 1 instead of bool) because it works... you previous answer didn't work after all